# Issues starting headless installation of NetBSD in VirtualBox

Tags: virtualbox, system-installation, serial-console, headless, netbsd

On a headless Ubuntu 22.04 machine, I'd like to start a headless installation of NetBSD 9.2 in VirtualBox.

I have a prepared virtual machine with a set of blank disk images attached, as well as with the bootable NetBSD installation CD attached to the CDROM drive.

My idea was to perform the installation over the serial port, using `minicom`, but I'm unable to get the installation to switch over to use the serial console.

I'm starting the machine with

```bash
VBoxManage startvm netbsd --type=headless
```

Then I try to get it to switch over the console to the serial port:

```bash
VBoxManage controlvm netbsd keyboardputfile boot.conf
```

... where `boot.conf` is a file containing a line of text saying `consdev com0`, which is what you would type on the NetBSD boot prompt to switch to the serial console.

I know NetBSD's serial console is set up to use 9600 8N1, which is what I have `minicom` configured to use, and I have set up the serial port on the virtual machine like so:

```
UART 1:                      I/O base: 0x03f8, IRQ: 4, attached to pipe (server) '/tmp/netbsd.pipe', 16550A
```

I start `minicom` using

```bash
minicom -D 'unix#/tmp/netbsd.pipe'
```

I successfully use the serial console on another virtual machine in an identical way, and I can see the status in `minicom` switch from "Offline" to "Online" as soon as the NetBSD machine turns on, but there is no output in `minicom`.

Can anyone see what the issue is and how I would go about fixing it? I know the alternative would be to PXE boot the machine, but I was hoping to be able to avoid doing that (as I don't netboot anything else at the moment).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was obviously thinking too much and reading too little.  The main issue was
that I got the installation ISO image off the main NetBSD website's front page, which does not contain a link to the installation instructions.

Had I read the instructions, I would have seen that there is a *separate* ISO image, `boot-com.iso`, specifically made for installations over serial console:

> Quick install notes for the impatient
>
> This section contains some brief notes describing what you need to install NetBSD 9.2 on a machine of the amd64 architecture.
>
> Fetch files needed to install NetBSD.
>
> - Option 1: bootable CD-ROM images or USB images containing the full distribution.
>
>   These can be found on an FTP site near you, usually located in the `/pub/NetBSD/images/` directory. Check the list of NetBSD mirrors for details.
> - Option 2: bootable CD-ROM images from `amd64/installation/cdrom/`.
>
>   These images are bootable, but do not contain binary sets. They are intended for network installs or system repair. `boot.iso` is for VGA console installation, **and `boot-com.iso` is for installation over serial console (com0, 9600 baud).**

Switching out the ISO image files, I now am able to start the installation the way I was intending.